Epicycloid from iterated power sequence with unit modulus
Given a starting point $z_0 = e^{i\hspace{1pt} \theta_0}$, with irrational $\theta_0$, define the sequence,
$$
z_{k+1} = z_k^p
$$
with integer $p\ge 2$. Apparently the sequence outlines an epicyloid with $p-1$ cusps. Is this known?
The epicycloid equation is:
$$
z(\theta) = \mbox{$\frac{p}{p+1}$}\hspace{1pt}e^{i\hspace{1pt}\theta} + \mbox{$\frac{1}{p+1}$}\hspace{1pt}e^{i\hspace{1pt}p\hspace{1pt}\theta}
$$
Plotting the first 1000 points, with lines between sequential points, for $p=2,3,4,5,6$ we get:
$p=2$:

$p=3$:

$p=4$:

$p=5$:

$p=6$:


What value of $\theta_0$ are you using?

@QiaochuYuan I'm using a random starting point. For some $\theta_0$ like $\pi/p$ etc. the sequence contains a finite number of points and doesn't trace the epicycloid.

For numerical reasons, you need to normalize the points each iteration in simulation.

I bet you'll really enjoy this Mathologer video.

@SammyBlack Thanks! Interesting connection with Mandelbrot like sets.
